# C# if condition is working correctly but else is not working?

Tags: c#

Here I was trying to match user id password with my database.
The if part is working correctly but else is not working in browser.
the code is below:

```cs
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ITD_ClientConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
connection.Open();
string checku = "select count(*) from UserRG where Pan = '" + txtid.Text + "' AND Pass='"+txtpasslog.Text+"' ";

SqlCommand cdm = new SqlCommand(checku, connection);
int temp = Convert.ToInt32(cdm.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
if (temp == 1)
{
    Response.Write("<script>alert('hurry ! welcome user')</script>");
}
else { Response.Write("<script>alert('password doesn't match')</script>"); }
```

Comment: Off-topic, but read up on SQL Injection and why your code is vulnerable to it.

Comment: When you say it's not working, what are you expecting to happen and what happens instead?

Comment: SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ITD_ClientConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        connection.Open();
         string checku = "select count(*) from UserRG where Pan = '" + txtid.Text + "' AND Pass='"+txtpasslog.Text+"' ";

Comment: You'll have more chances of having an answer if we can read your code. Also, if the `else` part is not working, this means that either your test `temp == 1` or the operation where you calculate `temp` value is wrong

Comment: i just want else part to work if my code doesn't satisfy if condition but if condition is working correctly if i enter correct user name and pasword but if not else part is showing message on browser.

Comment: but if not else part is not showing message on browser.

Comment: If the browser is “showing message” you need to tell us what the message is; it might be important.,

Answer (score 1):

problem must come from `'password doesn't match'`

You should try

`'password doesn\'t match'` or more likely`"password doesn't match"`

or find a way to get rid of the `'` in the middle